# Gitkit Java - Update photo URL

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-identity-toolkit

My goal is setting the URL for the profile picture of an existing user.
I'm using the `Google Identity Toolkit` Java library on `App Engine`.
Below is my code:

```java
GitkitUser u = gitkitClient.getUserByLocalId(localId);
u.setPhotoUrl(profilePictureURL);
gitkitClient.updateUser(u);
```

where `gitkitClient' is my GitKit client, already initialized with the right parameters, and`localId' is the id of the user I'd like to update.

This code causes the following exception:

```
org.json.JSONException: JSONObject["localId"] not found.
```

Documentation is hard to find for this library. I'd be glad if someone could suggest me what I'm missing there.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for reporting the bug. It will be fixed in one or two days.

[UPDATE] It's fixed. I manually tested and verified. Please also use the newest version of java library. You can get it from [here](https://github.com/google/identity-toolkit-java-client) or from maven update.

Comment: I have just tested my code after updating the Gitkit Java library to 1.2.8. There are no more exceptions, but the photoURL doesn't still get persisted. By looking at the code it seems to be managed as other parameters are, but when I get the same GitKit user again photoURL is still null.